# Change Author style at bst

Tags: author, custom-bib

I am a programmer but I really struggle with the bst lan.
After making the bst some times, I having now an almost fitting style but the authors are still at the wrong format. I am pretty sure I defined it right at cmd but I still get the ", " & " and " separators.
What I need is:

14Vgl. Mertens/Barbian/Baier (2017), S. 35.

This is how it looks right now:
[image]

What I need is the code change at the bst file. Thx a Lot!

EDIT:
I digged a bit and found this code below. As far as I understand it should concat the names and insert the separators. The code should insert the '/' as I want it but the PDF still looks like 'Name, Name and Name'. Could it be, I had run into a cashing issue? If yes, what I have to clean up/delete?

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, ff}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #1
          #1 + =
          numnames #3
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { "/ " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              "/" *
              t "others" =
                {
                  bib.name.font
                  " " * bbl.etal emphasize *
                }
                { " " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  t "others" =
    'skip$
    { bib.name.font }
  if$
  } if$
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I guess a clue could be found in line 42 of the bst file!?

Comment: Please tell us *how* you create the custom bst file. E.g., entirely by hand, or with the help of a utility such as `makebst`? If it's the latter, a solution should be easy to come by, as one of the utility's multiple choice questions deals explicitly with which separator symbol should be used to in multi-author citation call-outs.

Comment: @Johannes_B: no, no clue found. This was were I started first.

Comment: @Mico: I started Makebst several times until most stuff were correct and tried to change the rest manually. I am pretty sure I selected the right one (checked it afterwars at cmd) but the output was still wrong.